# React navigation 5 set navigation options with class components

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I recently upgraded the react navigation version in my project to version 5 but still using class components and will like to keep the class components. Unfortunately, I can no longer use navigationOptions to set the navigation properties for my class. I will like to get help on how to set the navigationOptions in a class component for react navigation 5.

```
const AppStack = createStackNavigator();

const app = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AppStack.Navigator initialRouteName="SplashScreen">
        <AppStack.Screen name="SplashScreen" component={SplashScreen} options={{ headerShown: false, headerBackTitle: null }}/>
        <AppStack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} options={{ headerShown: true, headerBackTitle: null }}/>
       </AppStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default app;

class Login extends React.Component {

static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const params = navigation.state.params || {};
    return {
      headerTitle: params.headerTitle,
      headerRight: params.headerRight,
      headerLeft: params.headerLeft,
      headerStyle: params.headerStyle,
      headerTitleStyle: styles.headerTitle,
    };
  };
}
```

Comment: use navigation.setOptions in constructor

Comment: Thanks @MuhammedYasirMT, that did not work. Getting the error "Can't find variable: navigation"

Comment: It should be this.props.navigation.setOptions